# Fetch API uploads corrupted Excel files to Dropbox

Tags: file-upload, fetch-api, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk-js

I'm using a Dropbox SDK JS (`"dropbox": "^10.10.0"`) to upload files via `filesGetTemporaryUploadLink`, this method returns a temporal URL for file uploading.

The way I upload a file:

```js
const fileUploadResult = await fetch(uploadDestination.url, {
    body: fileData,
    cache: "no-cache",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
    },
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors"
});
```

When I upload PDFs, everything is working OK, but when I try to upload `.xlsx` file, this file is uploaded in a corrupted way.

I've tried to play with `Content-Type`, but when I change `application/octet-stream` to Excel's MIME (`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`) or to `binar/octet-stream`, I get the error:

> *Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)*

That's quite strange, what's the difference between sending PDFs and Excel files via `POST` with Fetch API?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/issues/810 ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Greg [mentioned](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/issues/810#issuecomment-928269834), the problem was by unnecessary wrapping a file by `FormData`, once I've removed this wrapping, everything is working correctly:

```js
const fileData = domRef.files[0];

const fileUploadResult = await fetch(uploadDestination.url, {
    body: fileData,
    cache: "no-cache",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
    },
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors"
});
```